# How to parse a local XML file in Titanium?

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

My `Resources` folder contains an XML file. I need to parse it in Titanium. I have written the following code:

```
try {
    var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'Translation.xml');
    var xmltext = file.read().text;
    var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext);
}
catch(e) {
     alert(e); 
     Ti.API.info(e);    
}
```

But I am getting the next error:

```
 - result of expression 'file.read() is not an object
```

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check if your file exists or not.

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'Translation.xml'); 
if ( file.exists() ) {
        var xmltext = file.read().text;
        var doc = Ti.XML.parseString(xmltext); 
}
```

Comment: It is also giving file not found

Comment: Ya i am getting after deleting build. But i am not getting whole xml text. It displays only first line

Comment: see what it gives: `var fcontent = file.read();
 
Ti.API.info('contents = ' + fcontent.text);`

Comment: This statement also giving the same line

Comment: I am getting only first line of XML file

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/4031/parsing-xml-struct or http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/116501/parse-tidocument-result-from-titaniumxmlparsestring

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file can't be found on the system, that's why you are getting the error. Try putting the whole path as mentioned bellow. Example:

```
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile("../Resources/tableWindows/CrossRef.xml");
```

Somebody with the same problem: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123246/xml-file-will-not-read

Comment: or use an absolute URL: `getFile("/Resour..`